# error c2146 syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'StackEmpty'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm seeing about six errors when trying to compile using this class

## Header:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

template <typename E>
class ArrayStack {
    enum { DEF_CAPACITY = 100 }; // default stack capacity
public:
    ArrayStack(int cap = DEF_CAPACITY); // constructor from capacity
    int size() const; // number of items in the stack
    bool empty() const; // is the stack empty?
    const E& top() const throw(StackEmpty); // get the top element
    void push(const E& e) throw(StackFull); // push element onto stack
    void pop() throw(StackEmpty); // pop the stack                          
private:
    E* S; // array of stack elements
    int capacity; // stack capacity
    int t; // index of the top of the stack
};
#endif
```

## implementation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Stack.h"

template <typename E> ArrayStack<E>::ArrayStack(int cap): S(new E[cap]), capacity(cap), t(-1) { }

template <typename E> 
int ArrayStack<E>::size() const {
    return (t + 1);
}

template <typename E> 
bool ArrayStack<E>::empty() const{
    return (t < 0);
} 

template <typename E> 
const E& ArrayStack<E>::top() const throw(StackEmpty) {
    if (empty()) throw StackEmpty("Top of empty stack");
    return S[t];
}

template <typename E> 
void ArrayStack<E>::push(const E& e) throw(StackFull) {
    if (size() == capacity) throw StackFull("Push to full stack");
    S[++t] = e;
}

template <typename E> 
void ArrayStack<E>::pop() throw(StackEmpty) {
    if (empty()) throw StackEmpty("Pop from empty stack");
    --t;
}
```

This particular class is copied from my textbook for a school project where I can't use the standard library's stack, but I can use the text book's (for whatever reason).

The objects I have made of the class look like this if it helps:

```
ArrayStack<char> postfixStack;
```

Comment: So what is `StackEmpty` and how is the compiler supposed to know about it?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first line of the file. Any lines before that are ignored (assuming you're using MSVC++)

Comment: You use `StackEmpty` and `StackFull` which are not defined

Comment: @M.M Good catch on the header.

Would I need to define `StackEmpty` and `StackFull` as exception types?
I was under the impression I had them defined when I called `throw StackEmpty("Top of empty stack");`

Comment: `throw` does not define a class. You would need to create those types beforehand.  BTW it is considered bad style to use throw-specifiers these days.

Comment: Templates should be implemented only in the header.